# INSERT w/ SELECT Subquery and Duplicate Key Error

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a job queue that will have many schedulers and workers tapping into it, with some schedulers even trying to queue the same job. I want to make sure the same job isn't added if it's already there with a "pending" status.

The table has a unique ID field for code-generated UUIDs.
A distinct job is identified by its name and parameters.

```
INSERT INTO job (id,name,parameters)
SELECT '3aa39ed8-bac8-454a-88e1-626ce6e69228', 'process_summaries', '{}'
FROM job
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM job
    WHERE name = 'process_summaries'
    AND parameters = '{}'
    AND status = 'pending'
);
```

This is resulting in a duplicate key error on the ID, even though that ID definitely does NOT exist in the table beforehand.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to compensate?

Edit:
Since nobody seems to believe me..,

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM job WHERE id='3aa39ed8-bac8-454a-88e1-626ce6e69228';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO job (id,name,parameters)
    -> SELECT '3aa39ed8-bac8-454a-88e1-626ce6e69228', 'process_summaries', '{}'
    -> FROM job
    -> WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    ->     SELECT 1 FROM job
    ->     WHERE name = 'process_summaries'
    ->     AND parameters = '{}'
    ->     AND status = 'pending'
    -> );
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '3aa39ed8-bac8-454a-88e1-626ce6e69228' for key 'PRIMARY'

mysql> SELECT * FROM job WHERE id='3aa39ed8-bac8-454a-88e1-626ce6e69228';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: If such a job already exists in the database the `INSERT` will try to insert a record of all NULLs (as the `SELECT` returns nothing). It will not simply be forgotten or ignored.

Comment: You realize you're inserting **the same record** every time your `WHERE NOT EXISTS` produces a result? Also, the record 100%, undoubtedly DOES exist because the database won't start spitting that error because it feels like it. @Renardo your comment isn't correct.

Comment: I'm not sure.. But try `FROM (select 1) one_row_dummy_table` instead of `FROM job`. In MySQL you could just use `FROM dual`.

Comment: @Rikaelus How many records are return by the `SELECT`?  Just execute your query without the `INSERT` statement

Comment: @N.B. Obviously every time this query is run the ID will be a new UUID, so it's not the same record being added each time. It's the same *job* being added with the same name/parameter combination, but that's supposed to happen. It's being added as "pending" where all previous jobs have other statuses.

Comment: @Eric Zero. So the conditions are right that the INSERT should happen, but it's telling me the ID is duplicate. Of course I also checked that and it's most definitely not already in the table.

Comment: Alright, you must be correct and we have the first official case of gremlins inside someone's computer. Since you won't listen to reason, I'll suggest trying exorcism then, best of luck! :)

Comment: @N.B.What reason am I not listening to? Last I checked I'm the one with access to the table and I can unequivocally say that the ID doesn't exist before or after this query is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the subquery returns no row, the `NOT EXISTS (...)` expression will return `TRUE` (or `1`). In that case the query will try to insert as much rows (with the same constant values) as do exist in the `job` table, thus raising a duplicate key error for the `id` column. All you need to change is to select from any one-row-table. In MySQL you can use `FROM dual` or a subquery `(select 1)`. So your query could be:

```
INSERT INTO job (id,name,parameters)
SELECT '3aa39ed8-bac8-454a-88e1-626ce6e69228', 'process_summaries', '{}'
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM job
    WHERE name = 'process_summaries'
    AND parameters = '{}'
    AND status = 'pending'
);
```

You can also just wrap your values in a subquery (one-row derived table):

```
INSERT INTO job (id,name,parameters)
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT '3aa39ed8-bac8-454a-88e1-626ce6e69228', 'process_summaries', '{}') sub
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM job
    WHERE name = 'process_summaries'
    AND parameters = '{}'
    AND status = 'pending'
);
```

Comment: Were that true, wouldn't I be able to find the inserted ID afterwards? Because I can't. The ID it says I'm duplicating is literally NOT in the table after this statement is run.

Comment: @Rikaelus You are inserting multiple rows with the same ID.  While inserting the second row the error is raised and first row is rolled back (at least on InnoDB engine).

Comment: Okay, I get it now. The explanation is hard to parse when you don't already understand why it's happening. When I performed the outer SELECT without the insert I could see how the other FROM was returning multiple rows, each of which would trigger a new one to be added.